# User defined cron job node js

Tags: node.js, express

I have one requirement where i need to run cronjob/scheduler in node express, where user can set/update scheduler time.

I have explored cron module from npm , however i can not set dynamic cron scheduling.

Please find the code below

```
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

In above code * * * * * * will be dynamic or set by user.

Please suggest solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When the user sets the cron parameters, in that api call firstly stop the exisiting CronJob and then create new immediately after that using user entered values.

There is stop parameter mentioned in API here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron